# Why does it print "NO" even after so many conditions attached to it?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I found this question on Hyperskill and have been struggling with it. The solution was there too but it has made no sense to me.

In some design style, a 4x4 matrix pattern is considered looking pretty if it doesn't consist of a 2x2 matrix of the same colour. Your task is to write the program that outputs "YES" if the 4x4 matrix is looking pretty, otherwise output "NO".

The input contains 4 lines, each line contains 4 symbols, different symbols represent different colours: W stands for white colour, B - black, R - red, G - green, Y - yellow.

Sample Input 1:
WWWW
BBBB
WWWW
YYYY

Sample Output 1:
YES

Sample Input 2:
BBBB
BWWB
BWWB
BBBB

Sample Output 2:
NO

```
    String[] arr = new String[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arr[i] = scanner.next();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (arr[i].charAt(j) == arr[i + 1].charAt(j) && arr[i].charAt(j) == arr[i].charAt(j + 1)
                    && arr[i].charAt(j) == arr[i + 1].charAt(j + 1)) {
                System.out.println("NO");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("YES");
```

Comment: Then what's the problem exactly ?

Comment: How does a 4x4 matrix 'look pretty' ?

Comment: @Kayaman that's what I thought! But maybe OP has different tastes

Comment: I don't understand the question title. It prints `NO` because all those conditions evaluate to true. Even if there were a million conditions, it would still print `NO` if they all evaluated to true. That's how programming logic works. The algorithm in question is the most obvious one, compare 2x2 blocks for same color inside each position in the matrix.

Comment: I don't understand how this solution works to provide the desired result...

Comment: You don't explain what you find prettry in a 4x4 matrix (previous comments aren't just fun). We can't explain why it doesn't work like you expect

Comment: It prints no for every case because, he is not at all looking for all the possibilities, The code just looks at one possibility and returns. So obviously it is no!! Just negate the condition and print "YES" inside.

Comment: The line should have the same character and it should be repeated twice in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give my solution and explain why it works, I hope this helps.

```
String x="";
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    x+=scanner.nextLine();
}
//The above just combines the entire thing into one string length 16 to make it faster to code

boolean yes= true;
//preseted to true, if a uniformly colored 2by2 is found this becomes false

int[] topLefts = {0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14} 
//top Left corner of each possible 2 by 2 matrix

for(int i: top Lefts){//iterating over an array
    if(x.charAt(i)==x.charAt(i+1)&&x.charAt(i+4)==x.charAt(i+1)
         &&x.charAt(i+4)==x.charAt(i+5)) yes = false;
}
//This checks if the chars representing each box in the 2by2 are the same
//If even one 2by2 is colored the same, yes becomes true.

if(yes) System.out.println("YES");
else System.out.println("NO");
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. And also has runtime exception `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

It prints "NO" when all the "many conditions attached to it" are matched.
The program creates an array of 4 strings containing 4 letters. Then it sequentially checks the whole matrix like this:

```
if (1.1 == 2.1 && 1.1 == 1.2 && 1.1 == 2.2) 
    print "NO"
```

- _ .  1. 2 3 4
- 1 . **X X** *B B*
- 2 . **X X** *D B*
- 3 . *B C D B*
- 4 . *B B B B*

Then it shifts to the right by 1 and checks again until it reaches the end of the string. After this happens it shifts down by 1 and checks strings 2 and 3 from the beginning. Same for strings 3 and 4.
If the program finds 2x2 matrix of the same characters it considers the whole matrix "unpretty" and prints "NO".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I hope this helps:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[][] c = new char[4][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            c[i] = s.next().toCharArray();
        }
        boolean pretty = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (c[i][j] == c[i][j + 1] &&
                        c[i][j] == c[i + 1][j] &&
                        c[i][j] == c[i + 1][j + 1]) {
                    pretty = false;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(pretty ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}
```